# Blazor | OpenReadStream | ограничение в 500кб

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp, blazor

OpenReadStream имеет ограничение в 500кб.Мне нужно загружать до 3мб.
Поставил параметр maxAllowedsize вообще в  15мб.
Загружаю два файла.Первый 350кб,второй 250кб.
Прохожусь отладчиком  по первой итерации в цикле.Она проходит нормально,но при второй итерации,
на этом месте

```
await imgFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedsize).ReadAsync(buffers);
```

выключается отладчик и даже не выбрасывает исключение.Выключаются вообще любые действия на сайте.При перезагрузке страницы всё снова работает.

Проверил на 5 файлах,чей размер общий меньше 500кб и всё работает нормально.
В чем может быть проблема,что всё равно файлы больше 500кб не пропускает?

Сам код

```
    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AllImgages = new();
        IBrowserFile imgFile;
        string imgurl = string.Empty;
        foreach (var files in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
        {

            imgFile = files;
            var buffers = new byte[imgFile.Size];
            await imgFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedsize).ReadAsync(buffers);
            string imageType = imgFile.ContentType;
            imgurl = $"data:{imageType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffers)}";
            AllImgages.Add(new UserBlackListImage() { Img = buffers, imgURL = imgurl });

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;

    }
}
```

Для загрузки файлов использую

```
  <InputFile multiple OnChange="LoadFiles" class="form-control" />
```

Спасибо

Comment: какое значение задаёте для maxAllowedsize?

Comment: похожий вопрос на en so https://stackoverflow.com/a/74042356/312041

Comment: long maxAllowedsize = 1024*1024*15

Comment: [дока](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) (хз чем поможет, просто ссылки с гуглопоиска)

Comment: Я две ссылке выше уже читал и по ним пытался делать,но не работает

Comment: это какой то ваш класс UserBlackListImage? Может в нем быть проблема? (если что я не шарю, просто мимо проходил)

Comment: Там просто модель для работы с бд.  public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[]? Img { get; set; }
        public string? imgURL { get; set; }
        public int? UserBlackListId { get; set; }
        public UserBlackList? UserBlackList { get; set; }

Comment: внутрь `catch (Exception ex){ ... }` вообще не попадает код? Там логгипрование стоит у вас или брейкпоинт какой?

Comment: Как вы понимаете, что "не работает", в базу не пишется? Попробуйте хотя бы внутри foreach в лог вывести что он там читает?

Comment: Брейкпоинт я ставил прям в начала метода, чтобы посмотреть всё.Как и говорил выше, что при второй итерации цикла,приложение запускается после этой строчки   await imgFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedsize).ReadAsync(buffers);

Comment: а, да, код добавляйте плиз и подробности любые другие в вопрос, не пишите код в комментах, там его читать все равно невозможно

Comment: `при второй итерации цикла,приложение запускается после этой строчки await imgFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedsize).ReadAsync(buffers); ` я не понимаю этого текста совершенно, слова вижу, смысл не понимаю. У вас там await, потому это нормально, что какой то поток просто начинает работать сразу после этой строчки.

Comment: Вам придется более подробно описать это `сайт запускает дальше и даже не выбрасывает исключение` потому как эту фразу только вы понимаете. Что за чайт, почему он запускается на второй итерации, как сайт вообще может запускаться на второй итерации, а первую тогда кто выполнял? Это все только порождает больше вопросов

Comment: Вот немного ссылок в помощь лучше сформулировать вопрос  [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Окей.Суть метода - загрузка файлов.Сам метод срабатывает при добавлении файлов.Поставил брейкпоинт вообще в начале метода,чтобы смотреть поэтапно.Первая итерация цикла проходит нормально.Во второй итерации, после OpenReadStream(), отладчик больше не делает следующий шаг и отрубается отладка.

Comment: поставьте логгирование и брейпоинты руками на след строках после await. Отладка отрубается потом что асинхронный  вызов происходит и поток уходит что то другое делать.

Comment: для меня base64 выглядит странным, хотя это особо не должно иметь значения, учтите что перекодировка двоичных данных в текст значительно увеличивает вес картинки, зачем кстати вы в структуру данных добавляете картинку дважды? imgURL разве не должен быть ссылкой? вы туда по сути всю картинку целиком засовываете. Так быть не должно. То есть ответ с картинкой в 500кб будет весить около 1,5 МБ в этом случае.

Comment: Окей,сейчас посмотрел.После той строчки во второй итерации,отладчик же вырубается.Вместе с этим код дальше не выполняется полностью.Что даже логгер ничего не выводит.Так,что даже до catch не доходит.Вырубаются также все остальные действия и страница просто висит.При простой перезагрузке страницы всё снова работает.Считаю,что это из-за ограничений в 500кб,хотя размер повышен до 15мб,но всё равно не пропускает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38842 Ответ можно найти  в комментариях.

Мне помогло следующее

> Hi all, I took another look through the repro, and that behavior is by design.

Please note per the Stream.ReadAsync docs:

The result value can be less than the number of bytes allocated in the buffer if that many bytes are not currently available, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached.

That's essentially what's happening in this case. When a single call is made to ReadAsync, it only gives you the first (few) chunks that have been sent from JS, you are not guaranteed to receive the full file. Blazor subsequently throws an error as you've only read a part of the stream and the stream subsequently times out.

The way you'd want to achieve this would be by leveraging Stream.CopyToAsync or by using Stream.ReadAsync using smaller chunks until you reach the end of the stream. Note this is in line with our streaming and file upload guidance. Specific examples and sample code are also available in those docs pages.

Note in @huseyin-ezemi's comment above, they used ReadAsByteArrayAsync, that could also work as they're allowing the whole stream to be read. Note this may pose some security & scalability concerns as you're storing the whole stream/file in memory. This approach isn't recommended.

```
             var fileContent = new StreamContent(e.File.OpenReadStream(1024 * 1024 * 15));
             buffer = await fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

The above explains the behavior presented within @andrzejczar84's repro app, however in the original issue @Liero mentions running into this with CopyToAsync. This is more concerning, however I've been unable to repro. If @Liero, @angularsen or anyone else has a repro of this issue with CopyToAsync, I'd very much be interested in it. I'm marking this issue as "needs author feedback", it'll get auto-closed after a while if a repro can't be found. Though please feel free to re-open / start a new issue (and link this issue) if you do end up finding a repro with CopyToAsync.

Comment: Здесь StackOverflow на русском. Пожалуйста переведите суть ответа на русский язык.